# Manage memory while creating and returning collection

Tags: java, memory-management

I want to know better way for coding in terms of memory management,

```
    public class Cache {
      ......
      ......
      public List<EmployeeBDO> findEmployees(){
       ......
       List<EmployeeBDO> employees = new ArrayList<>();
       for (... : ...) {
                employees.add(...);
            }
       ......
       return employees;
      }
      
}
```

or

```
List<EmployeeBDO> employees = new ArrayList<>();
public class Cache {
      ......
      ......
      public List<EmployeeBDO> findEmployees(){
       ......
       employees.clear();
       for (... : ...) {
                employees.add(...);
            }
       ......
       return employees;
      }      
}
```

There are a refresh cache every 30 mn and there are 15 000 employees that we'll display it in dropdown

Comment: There's what's technically best for memory, and there's what is the only sane approach for maintainability and usability.

Answer (score 0):

As with all cases, the answer is "It depends ..."

If there is a single Cache object and only a single thread is calling findEmployees method, then the second option is better. employees list will be reused here.

If multiple threads are calling findEmployees method then you have to go with first option only. With multiple threads, employees  will be shared between threads and result in data race condition.

And you need to test for performance before deciding what option is best in therms of memory management.

Comment: In CacheManager class we inject it with 
-@EJB
    private Cache cache;

And we use the call of methode in 

-@Timeout
public void onTimeout(Timer timer) {
        .findEmplyees();
    }